# How to compute column by specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to query result like these picture.
First column select is this month plus next column by condition field (*SelectColumn*)

[image]

***yellow background is the select column for sum***

my example code.

```
    declare @myDate date = getdate(),@qry varchar(max)

set @qry = 'select case v.SelectColumn
    when 0 then (SELECT '+DATENAME(month,@myDate)+')
    when 2 then (SELECT '+DATENAME(month,@myDate)+'+'+DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@myDate))+')
    when 1 then (SELECT '+DATENAME(month,@myDate)+'+'+DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,1,@myDate))+'+'+DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,2,@myDate))+')

    end
    as SumColumn

from vwQC12Month v'
exec (@qry)
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem. A proper solution that does not require a number of CASE statements requires the months columns to be rotated into rows using UNPIVOT and then aggregations done on them.

Comment: Apart from 0,2,1 being seemingly the wrong way round (should perhaps be 0,1,2) the query builds and executes correctly so what's the problem?

Comment: @P.Salmon if case when 7 or more. Do I need to add a lot of case result _(SELECT '+DATENAME(month,@myDate)...._ i thought is a method that is not valid

Comment: Using your existing method you would have to add a lot of case statements. In my opinion it's a valid method if you are comfortable that it works, is maintainable, complies with the specification and resources you have been given and performs acceptably. Having said that I would compare your method to the unpivot/pivot method (which I think is more digestible) for performance before settling on a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem requires the monthly values to be accessible as rows such that selected aggregation can be applied. Typically, you can use UNPIVOT or VALUES to rotate columns into rows. Below is a working example using UNPIVOT.

In the query below, you'd have to change the short form month names to match your column names for it to work. Here is a working demo of this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/094e4/2

Also you might want to consider how you want to deal with year end wrapping and adjust the aggregation accordingly.

```
-- setup sample data 
create table Test (
  id int, Jan int, Feb int, Mar int, Apr int, May int, 
  Jun int, Jul int, Aug int, Sep int, Oct int, Nov int, Dec int,
  SelectColumn int)

insert Test values
(1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 1),
(2, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 2),
(3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 3),
(4, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 4)

-- query 
DECLARE @currentMonthNumber int = MONTH(getdate())

-- CTE that rotates the data into rows
; WITH RowsByMonth(id, SelectColumn, monthNumber, val) AS
(
  SELECT id, SelectColumn, CONVERT(int, month) AS monthNumber, val
  FROM
    (SELECT id, SelectColumn, 
       Jan AS [1], Feb AS [2], Mar AS [3], Apr AS [4], 
       May AS [5], Jun AS [6], Jul AS [7], Aug AS [8],
       Sep AS [9], Oct AS [10], Nov AS [11], Dec AS [12] 
     FROM Test) AS Source
     UNPIVOT
     (val FOR month IN 
      ([1], [2], [3], [4],
       [5], [6], [7], [8],
       [9], [10], [11], [12])
     ) AS asRows 
) -- aggregation below 
SELECT id, SUM(val) AS SumAcrossSelectedMonths
FROM RowsByMonth
WHERE 
  monthNumber >= @currentMonthNumber 
  AND monthNumber - @currentMonthNumber < SelectColumn
GROUP BY id

-- Results
| id | SumAcrossSelectedMonths |
|----|-------------------------|
|  1 |                      40 |
|  2 |                      90 |
|  3 |                     150 |
|  4 |                     220 |
```